# eTapestry API:obtaining the database ref

Tags: api, soap

i'm using the SOAP based api to update an account in etapestry. i want to get the $ref(unique database ref) for an account created i.e

```
$ref = "INPUT_DATABASE_REF"; // example: 1234.0.567812
```

how do i obtain the database ref??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the account ref will be present if you retrieve an existing account via methods like getAccountById, getDuplicateAccount, and getExistingQueryResults

Comment: you're a life saver user10!!..exactly what i needed..cheers mate!..i've now been able to retrieve the ref id using the getAccountById method.. :)